# How to turn OFF Schema Validations dynamically using MongoDB-JAVA APIs

Tags: mongodb

I have created a collection with schema validation as below,

```
ValidationOptions collOptions = new ValidationOptions();
collOptions.validator(sdoc);
collOptions.validationLevel(ValidationLevel.MODERATE);
collOptions.validationAction(ValidationAction.WARN);
srdmDatabase.createCollection(collectionName,new      CreateCollectionOptions().validationOptions(collOptions));
```

My collection is created successfully with schema validation.

In some cases, I want to turn OFF the validation check dynamically.

I found that there is an option to turn OFF the validation(ValidationLevel.OFF) in monogdb-java-driver, but I have no idea about how to use this option.
Please help me some one how to turn off the validation check programmatically.

We are using MongoDB-4.0 and  mongo-java-driver-3.10.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the use case? You can bypass validation on certain operations, and you can set it to warn instead of reject on validation failure.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In my case, I don't want to validate db for import operations, in this case I want to turn OFF the validation(ValidationLevel.OFF).

Comment: Validation adds quite small overhead, so unless you're expecting to import invalid documents, you can just leave it on to ensure your data integrity. Otherwise, `mongoimport --bypassDocumentValidation` or Java driver's [BulkWriteOperation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/BulkWriteOperation.html) (which should be used for large writes) has `setBypassDocumentValidation` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following code to bypass the validation.

For updates

```
collection.updateOne(
                Filters.eq("_id", 1),
                Updates.set("name", "Fresh Breads and Tulips"),
                new UpdateOptions().upsert(true).bypassDocumentValidation(true));
```

Similarly for inserts, you can use `InsertOptions.bypassDocumentValidation(true)`
Refer this link for more info https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/#bypass-document-validation